# Почему появляется NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, apache

Запускаю следующий код и появляется исключение, хотя методы красным Идея не подчеркивает:

```
import com.google.common.math.Stats;

public class SomeClass {
    static double[] testData = {12.5, 18.7, 11.2, 19.0, 22.1, 14.3, 16.9, 12.5,
            17.8, 16.9};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stats testStats = Stats.of(testData);
        double sd = testStats.populationStandardDeviation();
        System.out.println(sd);
    }
}
```

Comment: как запускаете и при чем тут апач?

Comment: запускаю кнопкой Run. попутал - думал эта из apache импортируется

Comment: Такое бывает, когда сурс код не совпадает с байткодом. Чтобы заработало нужно сделать рекомпаил того, что вызываете.

Comment: рекомпаил не помог

Comment: выборочное стандартное отклонение тоже не считается sampleStandardDeviation();

Comment: приведи стек исключения

Comment: У меня этот код работет. Депенденси отсюда взял https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.5-jre

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.math.DoubleUtils.ensureNonNegative(D)D
 at com.google.common.math.Stats.populationVariance(Stats.java:222)
 at com.google.common.math.Stats.populationStandardDeviation(Stats.java:242)
 at Chapter5.SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, в версии библиотеки, которую Вы используеете не определен метод, который используется в коде. Попробуйте поменять версию библиотеки на более новую (с версией 23.5 Ваш код работает нормально).

[Здесь можно скачать .jar файл или посмотреть зависимость для pom-ки](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.5-jre)